# Filtering numpy array of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, mask

I've got a np array of arrays and I want to remove all elements that match a condition. I want to avoid **for** loops to try to make it faster.

The np array is of shape [N,2]. I want to remove all sub-arrays where the first element is equal to zero.

```
[[1,2],
 [0,5], # <--- Remove
 [5,1],
 [0,3], # <--- Remove
 [1,1],
 [0,0], # <--- Remove
 [5,0],
 .....
 [5,5]]
```

I hope there is a solution with just one line of code. I just can't figure this line out. I hope somebody can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: So you have a NumPy array containing NumPy arrays? Or do you have a single 2-dimensional array?

Comment: `array[~(array[:,0] == 0)]` this will do.

Comment: Is this one array with shape (N,2) and integer dtype, or an array of shape (N,) with object dtype?

Answer (score 7):

Provided `arr` is your input array, do the following:

```
arr = arr[arr[:,0] !=0]
```

Here `arr[:,0]` correspond to the first element/column or each subarray. Then you check `arr[:,0] !=0` which returns you those indices where the first element is not equal to zero. Then these indices are automatically passed to `arr` which gives you what you want.